# Graphical card burned ? Help?

Tags: graphics-cards, power-supply

This is the second time that my graphical card burned. I purchased my compter on the website CSL computer there is little more than 2 years and the warrantly is out of date.

The configuration is :

- AMD Ryzen 3 2200G, 4x 3500 MHz
- MSI A320M Pro-E
- 16 GB ( 8*2 ) DDR4-RAM, 2666 MHz, G.Skill NT Series
- Boot SSD: 240 GB SSD Kingston A400
- 1To HDD
- Radeon RX 570 8 GB GDDR5 ASRock Phantom Gaming X
- Power supply unit : 500 Watt CSL ( constructor brand, this one : https://www.csl-computer.com/pc-zubehoer/netzteile/500-watt-csl.html )

The computer was built by CSL.

There is a little more than 2 months, the graphical card burned, with some smoke from the HDMI input. As the warrantly is out of date, CSL couldn't help us so I've contacted ASrock and they sent to me an other graphical card ( the same ).

Pending receipt the card, I use my computer without the graphical card and everyting works well.

This morning, the new graphical card burned too as you can see here : https://zupimages.net/up/21/37/gawz.jpg

The smoke is from the 8 pins port... I removed the graphical card and my computer works well just with the Vega graphics...

In your opinion, where did they get this problem from ? The power supply unit ? Just the grapical card ?

There is a way to test the power supply unit in order to see if there is any problem with it ? Or something else ?

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1):

There are small power supply testers that will basically tell you if the power supply can reach the required voltages etc. But its very different to a load test, which will look at the performance of the power supply under load.

You mentioned that you have had this happen twice with graphics cards. Where they both using the same power cable form the power supply?

I would be assuming its the power supply, but part of me wonders if there was issues with the mosfets on the RX570 that would cause this, I can't remember its going back awhile now, but they were a fairly large production run for AMD, and could have shitty mosfets (side note, my feeling is that AsRock use fairly low end components for power delivery, citation needed).

Anyway, the long and short of it is:

1. Assume the power supply is part of the issue and replace. If you don't want to replace but to test, I think you would need to take it to a decent power supply tester (check out 'Gamers Nexus' on youtube, they do some decent beginner level explanations that will probably get you on the right track).
2. Buy a replacement GPU after this.

Last note, could also be related to the power in your home, could be worth putting your PC on a surge protector and UPS (this can help smooth out power delivery and stop issues like these).